# Draw a circle with smooth edges

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm working with canvas im my application and I need to draw a circle.
To do that, I'm using the drawCicle(cx, cy, radious, paint) method for the canvas class.
The problem is that the circle's edges appear pixellated. And its kinf of oval.

This is my code:

```
public void drawCircle(){       
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(52, 73, 94));
    canvas.drawCircle(200, 300, 33, paint);     
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)`

This enables anti-aliasing => edges become smoother

Comment: It's smoother, but its kind ofpixelled yet. And its oval.

Comment: Read how anti-aliasing is performed, you'll understand why it's ofpixeled. Can't help with oval, not enough info

Comment: Alternatively, paint.setAntiAlias(true);

Comment: Sorry, I know this is late, but if you draw on Bitmaps, the problem even with anti-aliasing is because of redrawing without clearing the bitmap. I've covered this in more detail [here](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/android-why-your-canvas-shapes-arent-smooth-aa2a3f450eb5#.kill8q45y).

Comment: the only reason why that shape will be oval is if you transform the canvas before you draw it . A good practice is to save the canvas first, apply the canvas transformation, draw the transformed content then restore it so that next operations have a clean canvas .